# Is it safe to call BackgroundJob.Enqueue from inside a RecurringJob?

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a `RecurringJob` that receives some rows from a database and I want to send an email for each row. Is it safe to call `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` *within* the recurring job handler for each row to send an email?

My aim is to keep the work in the recuring job to a minimum.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you define as "safe"?

Comment: @TiesonT. Will it work ok? Will it cause strange bugs to appear?

Comment: I've added new jobs from within a background job, which seemed to run normally. I haven't _seen_ any bugs, but that doesn't mean there aren't any, I suppose.

Comment: @TiesonT. Great, thanks! Why did you do that instead of running everything from within the initial background job?

Comment: The parent job was responsible for building objects for persisting file info in the database, whereas the sub-job was responsible for generating images from the file and writing them to AWS. Doing it that way let me quickly show placeholders in the app, and then (using SignalR) I'd update the app as the processing status changed - the sub-job would update the database as it completed each step.

Comment: @TiesonT. Cool!

Comment: T'was. Unfortunately, I can't really answer the "is it safe" question definitively - there could be threading issues I didn't run into, or gotchas in how Hangfire processes jobs that (again) I didn't hit, just because my use-case was relatively simple. I *think* that as long as your jobs are atomic, you won't have any problems enqueuing new jobs. Might be worth posting to the Hangfire forum, https://discuss.hangfire.io/, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late to answer this but yes, you can call `BackgroundJon.Enqueue()` from within the recurring job. We use MongoDB and since it is thread safe, we have one job creating other jobs that run both serially and parallel.

Purpose of background jobs is to perform a task whether you start from an API call, recurring job or the background job itself.